# How to explain a theorem in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am reading a book "C*-algebra and finite-Dimensional Approximations". In the fundamental facts, it introduce the **Noncommunicative Lusin's theorem**:

Let $A\in B(H)$ be a nondegenerate C*-algebra with $A''=M$. For every finite set of vectors $F\in H, \varepsilon>0$, projection $p_{0}\in M$ and self-adjoint $y\in M$, there exists a self-adjoint $x\in A$ and a projection $p\in M$ such that $p\leq p_{0}$, $||p(h)-p_{0}(h)||<\varepsilon$ for all $h\in F$, $||x||\leq min\{2||yp_{0}||,||y||\}+\varepsilon$ and $xp=px$.

**Does the theorem above have some relations to the Lusin's theorem in real analysis?** Could someone explain it for me? Thanks.

Comment: Brown and Ozawa? +1

Comment: Yeah, the author of this book is Brown and Ozawa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo at the end of your question: it should say $xp=yp$. This is similar to Lusin's theorem in the sense that in the original theorem you have the continuous functions hanging aroudn betweent the measurable functions, and off a set of small measure, you can get your measurable function equal to the continuous function.

Here you have to think of $A$ as the "continuous functions", and $y$ is your measurable function. If $\varepsilon$ is small enough, the inequality will force $p=p_0$ on the subspace spanned by $F$. In other words, given any finite-dimensional subspace, you can find $x\in A$ with $x=y$ on the subspace.

So, this theorem has the same flavour as Lusin's, in that your "bad" operator is equal to a "nice" one over some set.

Comment: But, how to comprehend the "bad operator" in $A''$? Does the operator in $A''$ is not clearer than the operator in $A$?

Comment: No , it isn't, but of course it is a matter of opinion and circumstances. Reality is that you cannot do a lot with a measurable function; but  knowing that a continuous one is somewhat near might allow you to do some things. The same happens in $B(H)$, say. An arbitrary operator in $B(H)$ is a wild object. But for certain purposes you can count on the fact that a compact operator is near.

Comment: But in this theorem, for self-adjoint $y\in M$, we can find a $x\in A$ such that $xp=yp$. Does the element $x$ is "better" than $y$?

Comment: No, $y$ is "better". The point is that often your von Neumann algebra will be the double commutant of a certain C$^*$-algebra.  The point of this theorem is that, locally, you can express the operators in the double commutant in terms of operators in your algebra.

Comment: If $y$ is "better", why should we find a $x$ such that $xp=yp$ in this theorem?

Comment: My bad. I was mixing $x$ and $y$. The one in the dense  C$^*$-algebra is the "good" one.

Comment: Thank you verty much~ I think i can get the point of the theorem. :)